# NestJs TypeOrm loadRelationCountAndMap apply order by operation on it

Tags: mysql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am new in NestJs TypeORM and I tried to get the count only from the relation table using **loadRelationCountAndMap** method and now I need a fetuare to change the order of that count ASC or DESC but when I tried the **orderBy** method it will return me **unknow colunm** name.

Here is my query

```
await this.userRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('user')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('user.roles', 'roles')
    .loadRelationCountAndMap('user.postCount', 'user.post', 'post', qb =>
    qb.where('post.type =:type', { type: 'post' }),)
    .loadRelationCountAndMap('user.userSpotCount', 'user.spot', 'spot')
    .loadRelationCountAndMap(
    'user.itineraryCount',
    'user.post',
    'post',
    qb => qb.where('post.type =:type', { type: 'itinerary' }),)
    .where('roles.name = :name', { name: request.user_type })
    .orderBy('userSpotCount', 'ASC');
```

and the output is without orderBy method

```
[{
        "id": xxxxx,
        "name": "xxxx xxxx",
        "email": "xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.xxx",
        "facebook_id": null,
        "google_id": null,
        "apple_id": null,
        "is_email_verifie": null,
        "is_phone_verifie": null,
        "created_at": "2022-06-06T23:38:04.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-06-06T23:38:04.000Z",
        "phone": "1234567890",
        "token": null,
        "profile_pic": "",
        "status": "pending",
        "email_token": null,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "latitude": "26.78965",
        "longitude": "93.78965",
        "is_public": null,
        "basedIn": null,
        "visit_place": null,
        "visit_place_lat": null,
        "visit_place_long": null,
        "notification_flag": "on",
        "location": "abc, xyz, pqr",
        "country_code": null,
        "home_key": 1,
        "postCount": 0,
        "userSpotCount": 5,
        "itineraryCount": 0
      },
      {
        "id": xxxxx,
        "name": "xxxx xxxx",
        "email": "xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.xxx",
        "facebook_id": null,
        "google_id": null,
        "apple_id": null,
        "is_email_verifie": null,
        "is_phone_verifie": null,
        "created_at": "2022-06-06T23:38:04.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-06-06T23:38:04.000Z",
        "phone": "1234567890",
        "token": null,
        "profile_pic": "",
        "status": "pending",
        "email_token": null,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "latitude": "26.78965",
        "longitude": "93.78965",
        "is_public": null,
        "basedIn": null,
        "visit_place": null,
        "visit_place_lat": null,
        "visit_place_long": null,
        "notification_flag": "on",
        "location": "abc, xyz, pqr",
        "country_code": null,
        "home_key": 1,
        "postCount": 0,
        "userSpotCount": 1,
        "itineraryCount": 0
      }
]
```

I need this output as per the order by ASC/DESC

Comment: I think we are getting into the area of leaky abstractions: you need to see the generated sql statement to know how exactly it is structured, how the userSpotCount attribute is named in the query and you need to reference that field in the order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

The loadRelationCountAndMap method do a separated query to count the relations, it is the reason you can't sort by this.

You can do this sort by a sub query, something like it:

```
await this.userRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('user')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('user.roles', 'roles')
    .loadRelationCountAndMap('user.postCount', 'user.post', 'post', qb =>
        qb.where('post.type =:type', { type: 'post' }),
    )
    .addSelect((subQuery) => {
        return subQuery
            .select('COUNT(userSpotCount.id)', 'count')
            .from(UserSpotCount, 'userSpotCount')
            .where('userSpotCount.idUser = user.id');
    }, 'total_user_spot_count_sortable')
    .loadRelationCountAndMap('user.userSpotCount', 'user.spot', 'spot')
    .loadRelationCountAndMap(
        'user.itineraryCount',
        'user.post',
        'post',
        qb => qb.where('post.type =:type', { type: 'itinerary' }),
    )
    .where('roles.name = :name', { name: request.user_type })
    .orderBy('total_user_spot_count_sortable', 'ASC');
```

The problem doing it is that count for userSpotCount relation will be done twice but it works...